# How to know which IE Window Fire button onclick window in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, window, mshtml

There are more than one IE Window open and i click from one of them on button click so on button click event fire but i need HWND of IE window where button is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Write some identical data in session on page load

```
Session["clientId"] = GetNextClientId();
```

and get that value on button click

```
var clientId = Session["ClientId"];
```

hope this helps

Comment: But i m not create web base application it is window base application

Comment: i use mshtml.dll and shdocvw.dll for it

Comment: In Windows base application you have host winform or wpf window that hosts that IE, isn't it? keep that id there... describe more about your application, because it is not clear how is it designed